# Correct sorting of mysql elements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

For example, I have this data in column number: `M1, M2, ... M9, M10, U1, U2`. In the MySQL query I have: `ORDER BY number ASC`, but the order display as: `M1, M10, M2 ... U1, U2`. What can I do to make the order as follows: `M1, M2, ... M9, M10, U1, U2`? Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL has no built-in way to do natural sorting (which is what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: So, the best way to achieve this is simply edit data like: M01, M02 ... M10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you strip the first character, then cast the result to its integer value, you can do this:

```
...ORDER BY SUBSTRING(mycolumn, 1, 1),
            SUBSTRING(mycolumn, 2) + 0
```

Updated to show sorting by letter, then by numeric value following the letter.

Comment: Ok, it works quite nicely, but currently it is like this: M1, U1, M2..., is it possible to have the same letters first (M1, M2 ... U1)?

Comment: See updated solution above.